# Error when adding external JAR to Android AOSP build

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I am trying to add external JAR files (e.g., gson or eventbus) to my AOSP build. I tried it in two different ways:

- Adding them to `prebuilts/misc/common/mylibs/` and creating a `Android.mk` file for the dir. Then, I merely include the symbolic name of the lib in my app's `Android.mk` file.
- Adding them in a subdir `libs` in my custom app source code and add it via the app's `Android.mk` file directly.

However, both approaches are yielding me similar errors, the following for the second method:

```
ninja: error: 'packages/apps/Car/MyApp/packages/apps/Car/Myapp/libs/gson-2.6.2.jar', needed by 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/gson_intermediate/classes.jack', missing and no known rule to make it.
```

I noticed the weird repeating path in the error message. Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is my `Android.mk` file for the second way:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += jsr305 gson

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

include packages/apps/Car/libs/car-stream-ui-lib/car-stream-ui-lib.mk
include packages/services/Car/car-support-lib/car-support.mk

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := gson:$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/gson-2.6.2.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `$(LOCAL_PATH)` from the path fixed it.